# css background-image to continue from a div to another

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm looking for a way to have a png background image (with transparency) to start a first div (**with colored background**) and to continue in the next div but where it stopped from the previous div.

Let's say we have this structure :

```
<section>
   <div id="1">some text</div> <!-- background-image starts at the top and ends at the end -->
   <div id="2">some text</div> <!-- same background-image starts where it ended in #1 -->
</section>
```

but div #1 and #2 have colored background. We can have colored background AND background-image but I need to make sure the background image starts in div#2 where it stopped it div#1 and it has to be responsive of course.

I can't use background-image on *section* because DIVs have colored background and that will hide the background-image from *section*.

The goal is to use CSS only, but if the only way is to use javascript/jquery, why not. The problem if I use simple background-image on #1 and #2 is that the image will cut itself at the end of #1 and starts again at #2. And I can't use another absolute div because I need to be able to select the text or click the buttons in the DIVs

Here is an image to illustrate the idea.

- div#1 is filled with yellow, #2 is red.
- background-image is the green triangles with transparent background, just the triangles.
- you can see that the last triangles that are at the bottom of #1 would continue in #2.

[image]

Comment: Are the two divs always the same height?

Comment: Place an absolute div3 inside the section over div1 and div2 and put the background image in there.

Comment: @Turnip nop, they will change sizes with the content of the window's size

Comment: @Michel can't do it, as I said, I need to be able to interact (click or select the text) of #1 and #2

Comment: _"I can't use another absolute div because I need to be able to select the text or click the buttons in the DIVs"_ - then use z-index to position behind the elements.

Comment: I thought about that, that would work I guess but wanted to see if there was a "pretty" CSS solution instead of absolute divs

Comment: You could use a pseudo element rather than a div.

Comment: You can use the triangle image in pseudo   :before selector

Comment: On which pseudo element I should put the background-image ?

Comment: A bit more complicated than I initially thought. I think you might need another nested element: https://jsfiddle.net/vt1f26xe/1/

Comment: looks pretty good @Turnip thanks ! I'll work with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an absolutely positioned pseudo element to host the background image, though it would require another level of nested elements.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}

section::before {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100) repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

section > div > div {
  position: relative; /* Pull the content above the ::before */
}

section > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}

section > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div id="1">
     <div>
       some text
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="2">
     <div>
       some text
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the opacity. I forgot to say I need everything to be at opacity:1. I guess the absolute position of another div before #1 and #2 and play with z-index would do the trick

Comment: @hellodracon Don't see how opacity has anything to do with it. If you place a background image above a background color and the image isn't transparent, you won't see the color.

Comment: I've just set the opacity low because I didn't have transparent PNG image handy. Presumably your pattern is on a transparent background?

Answer (score 1):

> And I can't use another absolute div because I need to be able to select the text or click the buttons in the DIVs

to solve this problem exists `pointer-events: none;` and can be used to disable click events on elements with simply css, which allows to select or click stuff under the disabled element.

Here's my code with this solution:

```css
section {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.half {
  height: 50%;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url('https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/triangle/793jA5-green-triangle-transparent-background.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="half yellow">
    you can select me
    <br>
    <button>
       you can click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="half red">
     you can select me
    <br>
    <button>
       you can click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Solution is quite OK, but the text is behind the image and that's a problem. Z-index would do the trick. @Turnip answer is quite nice.

Thanks !

Comment: I've left the text and button beneath the overlay to better explain how css property `pointer-events` works

Comment: Both answers are good then. I can't validate 2 answers, can I ?